# Refresh binding of a form fields in ExtJs 6

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a wizard like tabpanel. One of the tabs contains a form. Everything works fine, but when I pass the form tab and then go to the previous tab again, the form's fields are empty. I inspected that the actuall viewModel of the form contains the correct data for the form fields, but the bindings still doesnt work.

can I do something like field.refresh() to refresh the binding and sync it with the viewModel?

I have bindings like this:

```
{
   xtype: 'textfield',
   fieldLabel: 'label text',
   bind: '{data.customerId}', //I checked this and it contains the field data.
}
```

Comment: try deep: true https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.app.bind.Binding.html#cfg-deep

Comment: yeah. 'deep: true' fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nikos comment points out deep binding needs to be used to keep the form field and the model field in sync; the syntax to implement this is as follows:

```
{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  fieldLabel: 'label text',
  bind: {
    value: {
      bindTo: '{data.customerId}',
      deep: true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're referring to an `Ext.data.Model`, then that's not correct: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/33ao

Comment: @Evan the config in the example you provided works for me most of the time, but under certain circumstances, like when I change the record in the view model (`data` in this example) not everything was syncing up on the form fields and using the syntax I provided here corrected that issue.